# How do I select the entire document except for a certain field?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select the entire document except for a certain div. In my belief the code below should work but it isn't. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document:not("#test")).bind('keydown',function(e){
  switch(e.which) {
  case 8:
  $("#status").append("<br/>captured");
  break;
  default:
  break;
  }
});
```

HTML to go with:

```
<textarea id="test" ></textarea><br/>
<input type="text" id="message"/>
<div id="status"></div>
```

I have also tried several variants of this

```
//$("*:not(#message)").bind('keydown',function(e){
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing an object (`document`) with a jQuery selector (`:not("#test")`). That makes it invalid syntax, as the selector should be inside a string.

If it would have run, you would have selected all document objects (the only one) except the ones with `id="test"` (none, as the document object doesn't have HTML attributes).

Perhaps you actually want to select all elements inside the body, except that div?

```
$('body *:not(#test)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Event delegation should make this simple.

```
$(document).on("keydown",":not(#message)",function(){
    alert("worky");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('*:not(#test)', 'html')` should work for your selector, you can replace * with for example div if your #test is div that way it would be faster and jquery don't check all controls uselessly.